# What's with Nino's reaction that make Miku jealous?

Tags: culture, the-quintessential-quintuplets

At around 13:40 in Episode 6 of *5-toubun no Hanayome ∬*, Uesugi said that he needed to go to toilet, then Nino said, 'sure, catch up with us later'. Then Miku gave Nino an unfriendly look.

What makes Miku jealous? I don't find anything improper here that indicates a relationship between Uesugi and Nino. Maybe the lines in Japanese have something to do with it? Or is it due to Japanese culture?

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you mean Fuutarou and Nino? Uesugi and Nino have spoken to each other only once in the whole anime: in S02E05 when Uesugi asks 'I thought you were really rich?' And Nino explains that the landlord rented them the kimono's.

Answer (score 1):

## Anime answer:

I seem to remember there was more to it in the manga, but going on anime only:

I don't think it's about Nino. Miku's just getting jealous ([I think it's jealous not envious?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tmx1jpqv3RA)) when someone else gets close to Fuutarou. I think it's the same as later on in

S02E07

> When Nino likes the nickname for Fuutarou that Miku comes up with

> [image]

S02E09

> When those girls get 'too clingy with Fuutarou'

> [image]

Also I was looking up earlier in the episodes if the chocolate may provide some kinda clue, but I wasn't able to find any.

---

## Manga answer (which allows me to have an anime-only answer actually) :

It's not so obvious in the anime but in the manga, Nino looks at Fuutarou longingly or something.

[image]

In the anime:

When Nino looks at Fuutarou longingly, Fuutarou isn't in the scene

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm asking about that very scene, not other arcs. In that scene, after Nino tells Uesugi to catch up, Miku seems quite jealous.

Comment: @Michael I mean this particular scene in the manga I remember there is more to it. I'm not talking about the future arcs. As for anime only, that's my answer. (Also, Do you mean Nino tells Fuutarou instead of Nino tells Uesugi? Uesugi and Nino have spoken to each other only once in the whole anime: in S02E05 when Uesugi asks 'I thought you were really rich?' And Nino explains that the landlord rented them the kimono's.)

Comment: They didn't address each other.

Comment: @Michael anyway whatever. added manga answer; updated anime answer